# Are there a casting problems in this case if ((x+(y<<16)) == ('a'+('b'<<16)))

Tags: c, casting

I have the following code

```
char x ='s', y='e';

if((x+(y<<16)) == ('a'+('b'<<16)))
    //do something

 switch (x+(y<<16)) {
    case 'a'+('b'<<16):
        //do something
        break;
```

Are there any casting problems in the comparison done in the `if` and in the `switch`?

Comment: are you missing a `MYMACRO` in the `if` line?

Comment: yes. I m  missing a MYMACRO in the if line

Comment: @chris When added, char will be converted into int.

Comment: @FeiJiang so the result of `MYMACRO` is int ?

Comment: @FeiJiang, Sorry, I've forgotten what exactly the deal is with C and `char`, but if it's a type with size 1, the bit shift comes first and moves it 16 places, which is bad. The other point still applies: The parameters should be enclosed in parentheses when used in the macro.

Comment: I updated the questio. I hope it's clear now

Comment: you can't have too many parenthesis to avoid surprises.

Comment: Casting problems, no.  Order-of-operations problems, yes.

Comment: @chris char in C is typically 1 byte ( compiler dependent ), however, in this case, it will promote the sum to an integer. Of course, it is better to be explicit and depend on the compiler's implicit promotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it your intention to bit-shift the second value by 16-bits, *then, then add the first ? If so, then you're going to have issues, because `+` has higher precedence than `<<`

The following two expressions demonstrate this:

```
'a' + 'c' << 16
'b' + 'b' << 16
```

Evaluation gives us:

```
printf("%X : %X\n", 'a' + 'c' << 16, 'b' + 'b' << 16);
```

The result is:

```
C40000 : C40000
```

This is because `'a'` and `'c'` are both promoted to `int`, the addition is done, then left-shifted 16 bits. Likewise with `'b'` and `'b'`. Since `('a' + 'c') == ('b' + 'b')`, the results are the same.

If you intended (or assumed) this instead:

```
'a' + ('c' << 16)
'b' + ('b' << 16)

printf("%X : %X\n", 'a' + ('c'<<16), 'b' + ('b'<<16));
```

The result is:

```
630061 : 620062
```

which I suspect is what you're trying to get to. If not, and you're relying on the current evaluation precedence, then you're probably fine with what you have.

**EDIT** Updated for change to question content:

There should be no casting problem per'se. All values are compiler-promoted to `int` for evaluation as currently written. If you're planning on assigning the results to something smaller than `int` you're going to have issues. Even a `short` at 16-bits won't be wide enough since that is your shift-depth. You need at least 24 bits of space for proper eval, and your implementations `int` will likely grant that unless you on some half-baked embedded system (I've seen stranger things).

Comment: I mean `'a' + ('c'<<16)`. I updated my question are there a casting problem in this cas ?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL updated answer per your updated question. I hope this finally gets what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to throw in some parentheses to avoid operator priority issues:

```
#define MYMACRO(X,Y) ((X)+(Y)<<16)
```

or else something unexpected may happen:

```
switch(MYMACRO(a+1,b+1)) // expands into switch(a+1+b+1<<16)
```

Comment: that's not my question and I will use the `MYMACRO` in this way `MYMACRO(a,b)`

Answer (score 0):

see what will happen when expanded like this

```
MYMACRO(1<<2, 2<<3)+1
```

So

```
define MYMACRO(X,Y) X+Y<<16
```

should be

```
define MYMACRO(X,Y) ((X)+(Y)<<16)
```

Comment: that's not my question. my question is about casting problems and not about preprocessor prblems. but this could be a good remark. Thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

There are no casting problems.

The Compiler will promote x + y to int and shift it left by 16 and then do an integer comparison.

For easier reading, you may code it as follows assuming you want unsigned int comparisons.

```
`if((  (unsigned)(x+y)<<16u) == ( (unsigned)('a'+'b')<<16u))  `
```